# How to print image from browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm able to print the webpage with the image using JavaScript. But it will print out the whole page with white spaces. What can I do to be able to just print out the Image using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Load images on your page with just the necessary resolution you need.
In your javascript, pass the highest resolution image url to Print.js for a better print quality.

Import printjs library:  printJS('images/print-01-highres.jpg', 'image')

Check this JavaScript library which provide much more options to print from html view.

http://printjs.crabbly.com/

https://www.cssscript.com/javascript-library-printing-elements-page-print-js/

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.open` to open the image in a separate window, then print *that*.

Alternately, hide everything except the image (using either JavaScript or `@media` CSS) before printing.

Comment: When I use `window.open` and print it, it will print out the whole page including white spaces. Can I hide those white spaces with CSS?

Comment: If you use `window.open` to open the image, there _is_ no page to print, there is no white space to hide. There is just the image.

Comment: https://imgur.com/LOr2yTL. This is the image page
https://imgur.com/h0BQnPi. This is the printing dialogue. 
You can see the huge white space around the image on the printing dialogue

Comment: That's because that's the size of the image. If you cover a big table with a small tablecloth, the rest is not table-colored; it's the table you didn't cover. Either get a bigger image to cover more of the page, or open a page containing some HTML(+CSS) to stretch the image to your liking.

Comment: I'll try it. Please post your latest comment as an answer, I'll mark it if I can get it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use html2canvas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to capture the image (s) of your choice from html page and print them. Below is is simple code for capturing image or check fork of one of such example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/mukund_kamble/pen/jexBzm)

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>

html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```